# Write a formula in a worksheet cell referencing cells in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am working with three Excel workbooks and a template.

I have a master (“Master”) workbook that has references to everything (using named ranges) and the VBA code to open the three other spreadsheets. It creates data workbooks and workbooks containing reports.

For one operation I have a spreadsheet, which I will call “Data”, that contains my data. In the template spreadsheet (“Template”), I am creating a report with data derived from “Data”.

I am asking “Master” to write into Column C in “Template” a formula referencing two different ranges in workbook “Data” in which I subtract one (Data) range from the other (Data) range.

I want Master to create in Template Column C a formula referencing two columns in Data (with QuantityTotal as one column and Miscellaneous as the other column).

This is what I want it to do.

```
Row1 Formula = ”Data”.Range(R1 & C(QuantityTotal)) – “Data”.Range(R1 & C(Miscellaneous))
Row2 Formula = “Data”.Range(R2 & C(QuantityTotal)) – “Data”.Range(R2 & C(Miscellaneous))
.
.
.
RownFormula = “Data”.Range(Rn & C(QuantityTotal)) – “Data”.Range(Rn & C(Miscellaneous))
```

I cannot hardcode the “Data” workbook name. It changes every time the script is run.

I’d prefer not to hardcode in any Data workbook range/cell references.
Data row references will change with each successive row but the column references won’t.

The Data column references need to be referred to by variable designations as those could change with future versions of my software.

I could get around this by creating a column in Data that holds the subtraction result of the other two Data columns but it would not be a clean way of handling something that I could do with a formula in a cell.

I tried every syntactical iteration I can think of. At one point I got hung up trying to reference double quotes in my formula string. I started to use Chr(34) where I want a double quote but other syntax errors were also impacting my results.

Comment: Would help to show us an example of how you tried to do this, so we can get some idea how your code is structured.

Comment: For example `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("C2:C10").formula = "=" & Data.Range("E2").Address(False,False,,True) & "-" & Data.Range("G2").Address(False,False,,True)` assuming `Data` is a worksheet reference. That last `True` argument to Address takes care of including the source workbook and worksheet reference.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can set a workbook to a variable. The simplest way is to reference it by name, but you've said it changes each time, so I'd suggest looping through each open workbook to see whether it *looks like* your data workbook.

I don't honestly know what you're doing with R1 and all that in the formula, so I'll focus on your question about getting the workbook.

For the sake of pure fantasy, let's say your Data workbook will always have a sheet called "The Data" and on "The Data", A1 is always equal to "ID".

```vb
Function GetDataWorkbook() As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If LooksLikeDataWorkbook(wb) Then
            Set GetDataWorkbook = wb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wb
End Function

Private Function LooksLikeDataWorkbook(wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Failed
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("The Data")
    LooksLikeDataWorkbook = sht.Range("A1").Value = "ID"

Failed:
End Function
```

Now you can use your function like this.

```vb
Dim dataWb as Workbook
Set dataWb = GetDataWorkbook()
If Not dataWb Is Nothing Then
    ...some formula stuff here
Else
    MsgBox "You need to open the data workbook."
End If
```